# Preferred signal report format for Digital Voice?

Tags: hf, snr, digital-voice

When using [FreeDV](http://freedv.org/tiki-index.php) or other digital voice modes, what's the preferred signal report? The software has a single [SNR](http://freedv.org/tiki-index.php?page=Microsoft+Windows+Quick+Start+Guide#Other_Features:) number, but that fluctuates quickly. Since it's a digital mode, you either get the transmission, or you don't, so the [RSQ](https://web.archive.org/web/20161009145610/http://psb-info.net/) system doesn't seem ideal.

Comment: With FreeDV, it's not true that you get transmission, or you don't. One of the great features of codec2 (used by FreeDV) is that it degrades gracefully: it has FEC which selectively adds redundancy to the most important data for the vocoder. Thus, a poor signal results in a lower fidelity, but still intelligible speech sound.

Comment: Well, it does glitch out at a certain point. There's no fading in the traditional sense.

Comment: Phil is right, It does "fade", just not in the traditional way we are used to.

Answer (score 2):

There is no standard preferred signal report for digital voice.  At the moment it's best to provide the number, and then explain where you got that number from and perhaps provide additional information as needed so the recipient can understand the meaning of it.

As digital voice codecs advance and as users seek to evaluate them a few key characteristics will stand out as being measurable, and perhaps someone will combine those into a single report and report style.

As it's fairly early on for the codec mentioned, and others, I expect that we'll have to simply report what we hear and see using plain english and work on making a standard.